# Pushing NULL object into std::vector

Tags: c++, macos, vector, stl

I have a class called `Pixel` where I only store the values `(x,y)`. Then I created a `std::vector` to store the pixels in a patch and compute some disparity.
Surprisingly, after some `Pixel`s are `push_back()` into the vector I get a NULL reference but I don't see why. Here's my code

```
std::vector<Pixel*> disparityPatches;
std::vector<Pixel*> patchPos;

//COMPUTE THE DISPARITY FOR EACH OF THE PIXEL COORDINATES IN THE PATCH
for (uint iPatchPos = 0; iPatchPos < patchPos.size(); iPatchPos++)
{
    disparityPatches.push_back(new Pixel(patchPos[iPatchPos]->getX()+dispNodeX, patchPos[iPatchPos]->getY()+dispNodeY));
    if( (disparityPatches[disparityPatches.size()-1]) == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "WHAT!?" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Can you see why is this hapenning? I've checked that `patchPos`has the correct data and `dispNodeX` and `dispNodeY` have the correct info too.
It's weird because the first three iterations (iPatchPos = [0,1,2,3]) work fine then i get the NULL reference.

**EDIT**

```
class Pixel
{
    float _x;
    float _y;
public:
    Pixel();
    Pixel::Pixel(float x, float y)
    {
       _x = x;
       _y = y;
    }

    const float Pixel::getX()
    {
       return _x;
    }

    const float Pixel::getY()
    {
       return _y;
    }
};
```

Comment: If your Pixel only contains (x,y) there is likely **no** reason to not just use `std::vector<Pixel>` and be done with it.

Comment: @WhozCraig That's not what the question is about.

Comment: @EitanT thus why it is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @WhozCraig I know. But so is "I like apples" :)

Comment: @EitanT an equally valid comment (and so do I, btw. particularly Granny Smiths).

Comment: Does it happen at random or always at the same position?

Comment: @BRabbit Are you using MSVC++? it may be that operator `new` fails to allocate memory and [returns NULL instead](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=167733). EDIT: didn't notice that the question is tagged [tag:osx].

Comment: It happends always at the same position.

Comment: What is that position? (and I see no reason this should be different, but does `disparityPatches.back()` likewise report as `nullptr` ? It should if this is consistent).

Comment: The parts of the code you show don't permit an explication of the phenomenon.  What is the definition of `Pixel`?  It's constructor (the one that is called)?

Comment: i agree with Eitan. try to separate the allocation from the insert by assigning the new result to a temp variable and test if for `NULL` before you insert it to the vector.

Comment: @BRabbit. I see no error. The problem looks like a wild pointer or buffer overflow elsewhere or, like Eitan T suggest in the constructor of the object being created.

Comment: @EitanT I'm working with Xcode.

Comment: For all others, I will edit the code, I don't want to paste it all though.

Comment: Assuming nothing has blasted over your vector nor the `patchPos` vector of pointers (I can only assume aren't smart-pointers since disparityPatches is not, and we are creatures of habit), *and* assuming your pointers within `patchPos` are *valid* (both very big assumptions), there is no reason for this code not to "work".

Comment: @EitanT MSVC++ throws `bad_alloc` when new fails, just as required by the standard.  (IIRC, VC++ 6 didn't, but that's ages ago.)

Comment: You are allocating *every* single individual pixel on the heap? Don't... just don't. Your code becomes much more fragile and hard to reason about with all those unnecessary pointers floating around, and it is slow as *hell* with the loss of locality and the ridiculous number of heap allocs.

Comment: Other than the `const` arguably being in the wrong location on `getX()` and `getY()`, (they should be const members, not  const retvals) there is nothing visibly wrong with `Pixel` (though I'm now curious where the default `Pixel::Pixel()` is implemented and why your `Pixel::Pixel(float x, float y)` is fully qualified. That compiles you say?). Your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @jalf well now that you mention it, how to change it so that it becomes better. BTW a good reference where heap-allocation = bad performance would be great.

Comment: @JamesKanze The support site claims that this also applies to other Express versions, such as MSVC++ 2005. Anyway, I made no assumptions about the SDK, hence my comment.

Comment: @jalf regarding better design, a simple question. Does each container *completely* **own** the `Pixel` objects within said-same? I.e., there are no two containers that "share" `Pixel` pointers to the *same* objects? If not, then `std::vector<Pixel>` is a good alternative. Otherwise, `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Pixel>>` is a considerably safer solution. [See this article](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C%2B%2B.pdf), for the fairly blatant reasons why.

Comment: Well I tried testing whether `new` was returning some error code but it doesn't. Then tried using the stack instead of the heap and it goes without that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You used below code to add a pix into the vector:

```
disparityPatches.push_back(new Pixel(patchPos[iPatchPos]->getX()+dispNodeX, patchPos[iPatchPos]->getY()+dispNodeY));
```

maybe `new Pixel(patchPos[iPatchPos]->getX()+dispNodeX, patchPos[iPatchPos]->getY()+dispNodeY)` may return null when the constructor failed in someway, so NULL will be added, then you got your error.

Comment: That would only happen on a non-standard C++ compiler

Comment: @dreamlax: or maybe if specifying a standard-breaking compilation/link flag.